# Retrieve data from Android DataStore and save to global var

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

I am making android app and I wants save configuration in Android `DataStore`. I have created a class and the values from `EditText` are correct save to `DataStore`. I using tutorial from YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEHVn9ATVjY
I can view the configuration in the config view correctly (textview fields get the value from the datastore):

```
private fun showConfigurationInForm(){
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    mainViewModel.readMqttAddressFlow.observe(this) { mqqtAdress ->
        binding.conMqttAddress.setText(mqqtAdress)
    }
}
```

This function show actual config in `EditText`, and this is great

But the config I will use to connect to MQTT Server, and how can I save the config to Varchar and use to another function?
I create var in class:

```
class ConfigurationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityConfigurationBinding

    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    var variMqttAddress = ""
    (...)
```

And in function `getValueFromDatastoreAndSaveToVar` I want to get and save values from `DataStore` to variable `variMqttAddress`

```
private fun getValueFromDatastoreAndSaveToVar(){
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    mainViewModel.readMqttAddressFlow.observe(this) { mqqtAdress ->
        variMqttAddress = mqqtAdress
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. when debugging I have an empty value in var

```
 Log.d(TAG, "variMqttAddress:: $variMqttAddress")

___________

2021-02-16 12:42:20.524 12792-12792 D/DEBUG: variMqttAddress::
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `flows` with `DataStore`, `value` will be fetched asynchronously meaning you wont have the value right away, try printing log inside `observe` method and then create your `MQttClient` with the url

```
private fun getValueFromDatastoreAndSaveToVar(){
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    mainViewModel.readMqttAddressFlow.observe(this) { mqqtAdress ->
        variMqttAddress = mqqtAdress
        //varImqttAddress will be available at this point
        Log.d(TAG, "variMqttAddress:: $variMqttAddress")
        val mqttClient = MqttAsyncClient(varImqttAddress, clientId, MemoryPersistence())
    }
}
```

other way is to use, `collect/first` on flows for blocking get but it requires to be inside a `coroutinescope`

> ***Quick Tip:** I think you can initialise `mainViewModel` globally once and access it in all methods instead of reassigning them in each
> method. Seems redundant*

**UPDATE**

If you have multiple values coming from different `LiveData` instances, then you can create a method something like `validateParatmers()`, which will have checks for all the parameters before creating instance like

```
private fun getValueFromDatastoreAndSaveToVar(){
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    mainViewModel.readMqttAddressFlow.observe(this) { mqqtAdress ->
        variMqttAddress = mqqtAdress
        Log.d(TAG, "variMqttAddress:: $variMqttAddress")
        validateParametersAndInitMqtt() //add checks after observing ever livedata
    }
    mainViewModel.readMqttPortFlow.observe(this) {mqttPort ->
        variMqttPass = mqttPort.toString()
        validateParametersAndInitMqtt()
    }
    mainViewModel.readMqttUserFlow.observe(this) { mqttUser ->
        variMqttUser = mqttUser
        validateParametersAndInitMqtt()
    }
    mainViewModel.readMqttPassFlow.observe(this) { mqttPass ->
       variMqttPass = mqttPass
        validateParametersAndInitMqtt()
    }
}

private fun validateParametersAndInitMqtt(){
    if(variMqttAddress.isEmpty() || variMqttPass.isEmpty()
            || variMqttUser.isEmpty() || variMqttPass.isEmpty()){
          //if any one is also empty, then don't proceed further
          return
     }
     //create socket instance here, all your values will be available  
}
```

Comment: I added an additional question as a separate post, not enough characters here

Answer (score 0):

Thank  you for your help

I did not add earlier that in addition to the address of the MQQT server in the configuration, it also stores the port, user and password.

I think I am doing something wrong, in every YouTube tutorial it is shown how to "download" one configuration parameter. My function that retrieves data now looks like this:

```
private fun getValueFromDatastoreAndSaveToVar(){
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        mainViewModel.readMqttAddressFlow.observe(this) { mqqtAdress ->
            variMqttAddress = mqqtAdress
            Log.d(TAG, "variMqttAddress:: $variMqttAddress")
        }
        mainViewModel.readMqttPortFlow.observe(this) {mqttPort ->
            variMqttPass = mqttPort.toString()
        }
        mainViewModel.readMqttUserFlow.observe(this) { mqttUser ->
            variMqttUser = mqttUser
        }
        mainViewModel.readMqttPassFlow.observe(this) { mqttPass ->
           variMqttPass = mqttPass
        }
}
```

in the repository class, I create a flow for each value

```
    //Create MQTT Address flow
    val readMqttAddressFlow: Flow<String> = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if(exception is IOException){
                Log.d("DataStore", exception.message.toString())
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            }else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preference ->
            val mqqtAdress = preference[PreferenceKeys.CON_MQTT_ADDRESS] ?: "none"
            mqqtAdress
        }

    //Create MQTT Port flow
    val readMqttPortFlow: Flow<Int> = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if(exception is IOException){
                Log.d("DataStore", exception.message.toString())
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            }else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preference ->
            val mqqtPort = preference[PreferenceKeys.CON_MQTT_PORT] ?: 0
            mqqtPort
        }

(.....)
```

now the question is am I doing it right?
now how to create MQttClient only when I have all parameters in variables?

can do some sleep of the function that is supposed to create the MQQTClient until the asychnronic function assigns values to variables?

Comment: is your `ViewModel` exposing a Flow or LiveData ? as you were observing to  `readMqttAddressFlow` instead of collecting

Comment: in class `MainViewModel` I have `private val repository = DataStoreRepository(application)` and  `val readMqttAddressFlow = repository.readMqttAddressFlow.asLiveData()`

Comment: Great as you are using Livedata, change the names of Flow to LiveData, it is confusing and I have updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Great, it works. I run the "connectMQTT" functions only when all the variables are present. I just have a question. Is this correct operation? I have a simple application and only 3 activities. same does it work in some complicated applications? For example, some e-mail client he holds the server address, password .. Lots of code, in every activity you have to run fun getValueFromDatastoreAndSaveToVar ()?

Comment: Ideally all those information needed would be part of a single response/ LiveData bundled together

Comment: also accept the answer if you think it helped to solve your question